# Git octopus merge with unrelated repositories

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a bunch of git repositories, each containing one file. I'd like to merge them all together, preferably in one step. What I'm aiming for is this graph:

```
*----¬ mergedrepo/master
| \ \ \
| | | * repoA/master
| | * repoB/master
| | |
| | * repoB/...
| * repoC/master
* repoD/master
|
* repoD/...
```

I tried a `git merge`, but it appears the octopus strategy doesn't work for disjoint trees

```
$ git merge a/master b/master c/master d/master
Unable to find common commit with a/master
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I was also told that `git merge --squash` would help, but that gave the same error.

This generates the right graph, but loses all the files:

```
$ git merge -s ours a/master b/master c/master d/master
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Your octopus merge will work, you just have to fix the conflicts like the message says. Once you've fixed the conflicts you should be able to just commit.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: There are no conflicts!

Comment: Yes there are: "Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.". To resolve the conflict, you probably just want to add all the conflicting paths if the files don't share any of the same names across repositories.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've managed to resolve the problem with octopus merge of unrelated branches.
Unfortunately the following applies only to rather simple cases where no real merge conflicts exist.

1. Do a merge as described in the OP.

   `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories a/master b/master c/master d/master`

   It will "fail" claiming about conflicts. But the merge has been performed and that fact recorded although there are no changes in the index.
2. Add contents of branches to the index with the `read-tree` command:

   `git read-tree a/master b/master c/master d/master`

   This will not affect working tree, only the index will be updated. (It is possible that you want to add your current branch to the end. You need to add all of them in one command.)

   If branches are not totally independent then adjust their order keeping in mind that the latter will overwrite contents of former branches.
3. Commit normally. (`git commit -m "octopus-merged remote 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'"`)
4. Perform a hard reset (`git reset --hard`) to get a consistent working tree.

I suppose one can later edit and amend this commit but I personally haven't tried this.

Comment: In case someone else is having trouble figuring this out: while you don't include the name of the branch you are merging into in the `git merge` command, you should include it in the `git read-tree` command.

Comment: For me adding the contents of the branches didn't work because I had to integrate 11 of them and git read-tree told me: **fatal: I cannot read more than 8 trees**. However by reading the trees one-by-one into the index with     `git read-tree a/master`   and then bringing them to the working area with     `git checkout-index -a`   it is possible to commit all the files at once and therefore overcome this limitation.

Answer (score 5):

Create an empty commit

```
git commit -m "Common commit" --allow-empty
```

look at its hash with `log -1` and add it to the grafts file without any parents

```
echo HASH_OF_COMMON_COMMIT >> .git/info/grafts
```

then find all other roots with `log --max-parents=0` and for each add their hash to the graft file with the above hash as parent

```
each HASH_OF_ROOT HASH_OF_COMMON_COMMIT >> .git/info/grafts
```

and now, merge!

The grafts file is a way to change the parents of a commit and once all your repos have a common commit your repo should accept the merge.

Answer (score 5):

I had a lot of unrelated branches to merge in from a legacy SVN structure to a newly initialised Git repo. [Vertigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393672/vertigo)'s answer got me most of the way there, but `git read-tree` can only read up to 8 trees at once.

My solution was to write a new tree after each read, then use that new tree in the next read:

```
tree_head=HEAD
to_merge="a/master ... z/master"

# If you're using a variable here you want word splitting, so don't use quotes.
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories $to_merge

for merging in $to_merge; do
    git read-tree "$tree_head" "$merging"
    tree_head=$(git write-tree)
done

git checkout-index -fua
git commit -m "All repos merged."
```

Answer (score 4):

While it looks more complicated, I think the solution from @akuhn is the only one that actually works the way Git intends it. Also for me the other solutions only work when I merge the unrelated branches once. In my usecase, I wanted to do successive merges with different versions of the unrelated branches. The other solutions do not throw errors, but the file state gets messed up.

The outlined solution actually got a lot easier since Git 1.6.5, which introduced the `git replace` command. The idea is still the same though: You make Git think that your commits have a common commit to make the merge work. To do that, you need to figure out the SHA-1 of the initial commit of your current branch:

```sh
common_commit=$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)
```

Once you have that, you tell git that each of the branches you want to merge originates from that commit:

```sh
for branch in a/master b/master c/master d/master
do
  branch_initial_commit=$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 $branch)
  git replace --graft $branch_initial_commit $common_commit
done
```

After that, you can simply run the merge command. Git will not complain, since all branches now originate from the same common commit.

```sh
git merge a/master b/master c/master d/master
```