# Unable to find common commit

Tags: git

When i'm running `git octopus origin/features/* origin/master` i get the following error: `Unable to find common commit with refs/remotes/origin/features/<branch>`

Tree is as follow:
[image]

Is there anyway to fix this, and making the octopus merge succeed?

Comment: try merging them one by one and, if you _really_ want to have a single revision with multiple parents as the end result (and not the one-by-one process), use git commit-tree using all the branches you wanted as the parents and providing the tree object of the branch you ended up with then you merged them one by one. That should be good enough.

Comment: so you really have history which did notstart at single point, but has several starts? why it has this form? do those histories have files with same name and how do you think they should be combined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git octopus merge with unrelated repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874149/git-octopus-merge-with-unrelated-repositories)